# Local notification scheduling issue

Tags: iphone, ios, uilocalnotification

I've set up a local Notification and my problem is that I've set it to saturday and with the repeatinterval of one week. However, I set the correct date up but I still get it every sunday but on the correctly set time. Does anybody see my mistake? Oh and dont to forget, if I set the correct day if its ...wednesday I get immediately a notifi after one minute. Don't know where's my fault.

```
    - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)applicatio
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar] ;

    NSDateComponents *componentsForReferenceDate =

    [calendar components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit ) fromDate:[NSDate date]];

    //set day (saturday)

    [componentsForReferenceDate setDay:1] ;
    [componentsForReferenceDate setMonth:12] ;
    [componentsForReferenceDate setYear:2012] ;

    NSDate *referenceDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:componentsForReferenceDate] ;

    // set components for time 18:30. 

    NSDateComponents *componentsForFireDate =

    [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit| NSSecondCalendarUnit ) fromDate: referenceDate];

    [componentsForFireDate setHour: 18] ;
    [componentsForFireDate setMinute:38] ;
    [componentsForFireDate setSecond:0] ;

    NSDate *fireDateOfNotification = [calendar dateFromComponents: componentsForFireDate];

    // Create the notification

    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]  init] ;

    notification.fireDate = fireDateOfNotification ;
    notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone] ;
    notification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"You are missed!"] ;
    notification.alertAction = @"Back";
    notification.userInfo= [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some information"] forKey:@"information"];
    notification.repeatInterval= NSWeekCalendarUnit ;
    notification.soundName = @"Appnotifisound.wav";
    notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification] ;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are creating two different `NSDateComponents`. One to set the Date, Month and Year, and a different one to set the Hours, Mins and Secs.

This should work :

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar] ;    
    NSDateComponents *componentsForReferenceDate = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

    //set day (saturday)

    [componentsForReferenceDate setDay:7] ;
    [componentsForReferenceDate setMonth:12] ;
    [componentsForReferenceDate setYear:2012] ;

    // set time (08:30 PM) 

    [componentsForReferenceDate setHour: 20] ;
    [componentsForReferenceDate setMinute:30] ;
    [componentsForReferenceDate setSecond:00] ;

    NSDate *fireDateOfNotification = [calendar dateFromComponents: componentsForReferenceDate];

    // Create the notification

    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]  init] ;

    notification.fireDate = fireDateOfNotification ;
    notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone] ;
    notification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"You are missed!"] ;
    notification.alertAction = @"Back";
    notification.userInfo= [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some information"] forKey:@"information"];
    notification.repeatInterval= NSWeekCalendarUnit ;
    notification.soundName = @"Appnotifisound.wav";
    notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification] ;

}
```